# How to initialize ObservableCollection with a values?

Tags: c#

I have such a class

```
    public class ClipProcessingGridItem
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MCGeoCalibFolder> GeoCalibrationFolders { get; }
                = new ObservableCollection<MCGeoCalibFolder>();
    }
```

and now I have `List<MCGeoCalibFolder>` and I would like to pass this list to `ObservableCollection<MCGeoCalibFolder>`

Like this

```
var s = new ClipProcessingGridItem
{
    GeoCalibrationFolders  = GetMyListOfData();
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ObservableCollection<T>` [`constructor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_ObjectModel_ObservableCollection_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_List__0__) accepting a `List<T>` parameter, like this

```cs
var s = new ClipProcessingGridItem
{
    GeoCalibrationFolders = new ObservableCollection<MCGeoCalibFolder>(GetMyListOfData());
}
```